# Lifecycle hooks failing with error 137

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, devops, lifecycle

I am launching Jobs and I'm trying to use the lifecycle hooks to launch a script at start and another one at shutdown of the container.

I am also specifying resource limits, and they look like this:

```
resources:
    required:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: 1
    limits:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: 1
```

My cluster currently has **4 nodes with 1  CPU and 4 GB of RAM each**, and is running on EC2 machines.

The `postStart` script is at the moment very simple, and looks like this:

```
export SOME_VAR=some_value
node someScript.js
```

The only thing the Node script does is update a value on a database, so it's not an especially intensive task.

After launching the job, the following events happen:

[image: Kubectl Events]

As you can see the `postStart` hook fails with error 137, and gives no error message.

Any help for solving this issue is highly welcome and appreciated.

### Edit 1

Since the first answer has pointed to the fact that the command executed for the cook might not be correctly built, I think it's important to say that I build the jobs using the API Kubernetes publishes through `kubectl proxy`.

This is how I specify the `lifecycle` instructions:

```
"lifecycle": {
    "postStart": {
        "exec": {
            "command": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "postStart.sh"
             ]
        }
    },
    "preStop": {
        "exec": {
            "command": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "preStop.sh"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I think this translates to YAML the way it's supposed to; please correct me if I am wrong on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems, so you get 2 answers :-)

## Problem 1: too high cpu requirement

You pod specifies the requirement of `cpu: 1` - this means 1 cpu core. Your nodes have 1 cpu core in total, but are already running some pods, like kube-proxy. So none of them have a full core available for your application, so the scheduling fails.

The error message `No nodes are available that match all of the predicates: Insufficient cpu (4), PodToleratesNodeTaints (1)` means:

- Scheduling is not possible at the moment
- Of all nodes, 4 do not have enough cpu to schedule this pod.

  - You can verify this by executing `kubectl describe node nameofyournode`, and look at the `Allocatable:` and the `Allocated resources:` part of the output. In `Non-terminated Pods:` you will see that is taking up some of your cpu, possibly a kube-proxy pod.
- Of all nodes, 1 has a [taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) that is not [tolerated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) by the pod (this is the master I imagine)

The solution is to lower the requirement for your pod (`500mi` means 500 millicores, or 0.5 cores):

```
resources:
  required:
    memory: 1Gi
    cpu: 500mi
  limits:
    memory: 1Gi
    cpu: 500mi
```

... or resize your machines so they have 2 cores instead of 1.

## Problem 2: bad postStart command

Now what is most curious is that somehow in the end the pod did get scheduled, but thereafter killed. Code 126 means `Command invoked cannot execute`, so the `postStart:` command is probably invalid. You did not post the full yaml file, but from the error message it looks like you have specified something like:

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh postStart.sh"]
```

please check if that is the case. If so, it is incorrect. You need to separate each parameter into a different element in the `command` array like so:

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh", "postStart.sh"]
```

Alternatively, make sure that `postStart.sh` is marked executable in the container image and specify a shell shebang in the first line (`#!/bin/bash`). If you do that you can define the postStart hook like this:

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/path/to/postStart.sh"]
```

Comment: Regarding *problem 1*, your explanation has helped me understand better Kubernetes and the scheduling system. As for the *problem 2*, I think there is no problem with the command, although I should've said that I launch my pods using the API (JSON) and not a YML file. I updated the post adding additional info. I'm still getting an error with the execution of the script.

Comment: i am having same issue too, no solution anywhere , error below2021-04-14T20:21:47Z [Warning] Exec lifecycle hook ([/bin/sh s3_script.sh restore]) for Container "notebook" in Pod "jupyter-vivek_jhub(52bd98e0-e881-4afa-a7cc-1eb529a9d21d)" failed - error: command '/bin/sh s3_script.sh restore' exited with 127: /bin/sh: 0: Can't open s3_script.sh , message: "/bin/sh: 0: Can't open s3_script.sh\n"